# Print five star ratings and reviews

Tags: theming, rating

I am using [Fivestar](https://www.drupal.org/project/fivestar) rating in custom print. See image:

[image]

I'm trying to print a fivestar as follows:

```
$your_average = $variables['result']['node']->field_rating['und'][0]['average'];
$your_maximum = "100";
print theme('fivestar_static', $your_average, $your_maximum);
```

But, I'm getting the following error:

> Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in /var/www/html/book1/includes/theme.inc on line 1088

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the definition of `fivestar_static` theme-function in `fivestar.module` file under `fivestar_theme()`, you need to provide the theme function with an array including the following keys: `rating`, `stars`, `tag`. A working example should look like:

```
$fivestar_variables = array('rating' => $your_average, 'stars' => $your_maximum);
print theme('fivestar_static', $fivestar_variables);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:-

```
$your_maximum="100";
$your_average  = "21";
print render(theme('fivestar_static', $your_average, $your_maximum ));
```

Comment: I have tried this, but not working. I am getting the same error.